# getChildren method and Javafx

Tags: eclipse, javafx

Any clues as to why I cannot use getChildren (two lines up from bottom) in the Javafx code below.  Eclipse is telling me to configure the build path.....but not what to configure it to.

Basically I am trying to draw two rectangle shapes but struggling with the basics.  If there is another way of achieving the same outcome then please share.  Many thanks in advance!!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class drawtriangle1 extends Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
 }

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     primaryStage.setTitle("hello world");
     Group root = new Group();
     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);

     Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(30, 30, 100, 50);
     rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE);

     Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 100);
     rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);



     root.getChildren().add(rect1);
     root.getChildren().add(rect2);


     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: I am going to guess that your setup is not correct. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: if you providing a full stack trace instead of your interpretation may be helpful ...

Comment: thank you...….will look to secure a stack trace